# Json Web API binding to Model Sometimes Throws Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have a WebAPI (not sure what version but it was created in VS2017) that receives a Json string and binds it to a model in the controller.  Most of the time this works just fine.  Occasionally it will throw an exception the first time I try to access the class instance.  It is clear the binding routines are failing but the exception message is no help: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  I am guessing that the binder is failing and not even creating an empty instance of my object.

I log the Json string before I call the API so I can review the string for issues.  I have identified that certain unicode symbols (such as the Trademark TM) will cause a failure, so I am managing those.

But I have a couple of recent Json strings that are throwing the exception and I cannot figure out why. There are no unicode symbols that I can locate.  Now my users are asking why this certain style of job is failing.

It seems that once the InputStream is read by the inner MVC binding routines, it can never be read again.  The trick of:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
string streamresult = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferedInputStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

throws it own exception, saying call was made before "the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream".

- Is there a way to peek inside the binder and see what it is choking
  on?
- or  Is there a way to get a better exception message?
- or  to capture and log the incoming data stream?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the Request Body, you will need to enable *rewind* on its stream, otherwise the request body can be read only once since by default it's a forward-only stream.

If you are using ASP.NET Core MVC, you could enable the rewind on your startup code with:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {  // <----
        context.Request.EnableRewind();
        await next();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

For your last point I can recommend the [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) library with its [Audit.WebApi](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WebApi/README.md) extension.

Comment: My API does not have startup code.  
Do I need to add the Owin packages and an Owin Startup Class to use this recommendation?

I will look over the documentation for Audit.Net